# boost::make_shared<T>(...) does not compile, shared_ptr<T>(new T(...)) does

Tags: boost, c++11, shared-ptr

I am getting compilation error with g++4.6 and boost 1.42 when using `boost::make_shared<T>(...)`, whereas `shared_ptr<T>(new T(...))` compiles just fine. I am unfortunately not able to isolate a minimal example (anything I tried compiled just fine for both), but perhaps someone could explain to me the difference.

I am instatiating an instance of `shared_ptr<ResidualsFunctor> f`, where `ResidualsFunctor` has the following ctor:

```
ResidualsFunctor(int,int,StaticEquilibriumSolver*)
```

This

```
f=shared_ptr<ResidualsFunctor>(new ResidualsFunctor(0,0,this)); // this is a StaticEquilibriumSolver*
```

compiles just fine, whereas

```
f=make_shared<ResidualsFunctor>(0,0,this);
```

tells me:

```
/usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/make_shared.hpp: In function 'boost::shared_ptr<T> boost::make_shared(Args&& ...) [with T = StaticEquilibriumSolver::ResidualsFunctor, Args = int, int, StaticEquilibriumSolver* const]':
pkg/sparc/SparcField.cpp:472:49:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/make_shared.hpp:148:5: error: no matching function for call to 'forward(int&)'
/usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/make_shared.hpp:148:5: note: candidate is:
/usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/make_shared.hpp:90:40: note: template<class T> T&& boost::detail::forward(T&&)
```

Is it a bug in boost? In gcc? My fault which I don't see?

Comment: This looks like an odd interaction between Boost's equivalent of `std::forward` and your compiler. What compiler version are you using, and what version of Boost are you using?

Comment: It is specified in the question, g++4.6 and boost 1.42.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`boost::make_shared` allocates an object of the given type, using the given parameters and wraps it in a `boost::shared_ptr`. Therefore, it has to forward the arguments you give it to a constructor. In order for your call to it to work, it must be able to find a constructor that matches the argument list you give it.

Your problem seems to be that it is having difficulty forwarding your integer arguments. I'm not sure how, as all of your arguments are basic types.

Boost 1.42 was released 18 months ago; GCC 4.6 was released rather more recently than that. I'd guess that if you update to a more recent version of Boost, you wouldn't have this problem.

Comment: `boost::make_shared` works just fine in other cases, that's why I don't understand what's going here...

Comment: @euxodos - The rules for forwarding and rvalue references have changed during these 18 months. Seems like the compiler and the library are coded against different sets of rules.

Comment: I am not able to update boost system-wide ATM, though I am glad the source of the problem is clear.